# How to rewrite base path (i.e. "/") with IIS rewrite?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

How do I rewrite site's base path (i.e. `/`) using IIS rewrite?

I've tried this so far:

```
<rule name="RewriteIndexUrl" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
</rule>
```

Currently it's not rewriting that base path, and it's returning the `index.html` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure out a possible solution and it worked:

1. Remove all default documents in IIS site (i.e. `index.html`, `index.htm`, `default.aspx`...)
2. Add the following rewriting rule:

```
<rule name="RewriteIndexUrl" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="false" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
</rule>
```